# PHP: Comparing two DateTime objects with different timezones

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

How does PHP compare `DateTime` objects when using conditional operators (`<`, `>`, `>=`, `<=`) ?

Is this comparison **timezone** invariant?

I tried below code and It looks like it is timezone invariant, can anyone confirm?

**Code:**

```
$datestr = "2015-10-09 10:28:01";
$dt = new DateTime($datestr);
$nowdate = new DateTime("now",new DateTimeZone("CET"));
print_r($dt);
echo "<br/>";
print_r($nowdate);
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($nowdate<$dt);
```

**Output:**

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-10-09 10:28:01 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris ) 
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-10-09 10:53:42 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => CET ) 
boolean false
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#example-2490):

> As of PHP 5.2.2, DateTime objects can be compared using comparison operators.

You've chosen a very confusing example that includes a fixed date that's not clear if it's supposed to be in the past and a time zone that's currently not active (it's CEST here in Western Europe until the end of October). Whatever, I see nothing wrong in your output: `2015-10-09 10:53:42 CET` (which equals `2015-10-09 09:53:42 UTC`) is clearly greater than `2015-10-09 10:28:01 Europe/Paris` (which equals `2015-10-09 08:28:01 UTC`).

With a slightly better example we can guess the operands do work as expected:

```
    echo "Same date:\n";
    $a = new DateTime('2015-01-31 01:23:45 UTC');
    $b = new DateTime('2015-01-31 02:23:45 Europe/Paris');
    var_dump($a, $b, $a<$b, $a==$b, $a>$b);
    echo "\n";

    echo "First greater than second:\n";
    $a = new DateTime('2015-01-31 01:23:46 UTC');
    $b = new DateTime('2015-01-31 02:23:45 Europe/Paris');
    var_dump($a, $b, $a<$b, $a==$b, $a>$b);
    echo "\n";

    echo "First less than second:\n";
    $a = new DateTime('2015-01-31 01:23:45 UTC');
    $b = new DateTime('2015-01-31 02:23:46 Europe/Paris');
    var_dump($a, $b, $a<$b, $a==$b, $a>$b);
```

```
Same date:
[...]
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)

First greater than second:
[...]
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)

First less than second:
[...]
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

[Demo with full code](https://3v4l.org/qPhOH).

Another example:

```
$date_2014 = new DateTime('2014-12-31 23:00:00 -07:00');
$date_2015 = new DateTime('2015-01-01 05:00:00 Asia/Tokyo');
var_dump($date_2014<$date_2015); // bool(false)
```

Comment: Well explained. Thanks @Álvaro G. Vicario

Comment: I find dates very difficult to grasp. That's why I studied harder :)

Comment: I have two date with different  timezone. And both dates have timezone offset.  And I want difference between two dates in seconds or minutes or hours.

Comment: @YatinMistry You can ask questions with the "Ask Question" button you can find in the top right corner of the site. Comment boxes are intended to leave remarks about specific questions or answers.

Answer (score -2):

The problem with the above code is the usage of different time-zone type.

PHP has three types of time-zone:

- A UTC offset, such as in new DateTime( "2015-02-29 -0500" );
- A timezone abbreviation, such as in new DateTime( "2015-02-29 EST" );
- A timezone identifier, such as in new DateTime( "2015-02-29 America/Montreal" );

If you compare two datetime objects with different time-zone types it will not give you appropriate result.

In your case the time-zones are type 2 and type 3. Use same time-zone types and it will give you proper result.

Comment: If comparison operators work at all it's because someone wrote a specific implementation for DateTime objects. In that case, it's hard to believe he forgot about two of the three properties ;-)

Comment: looks like the same case to me ;-)